# top mycart link layout

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation, toplinks

I'm using magento 1.9 with a custom theme, I didn't build it, I inherited it and its a bit of a mess, but at least functional. My question is 
[image]

There is no space between 'my cart and 'checkout'

What can I do to fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took a quick look at your website. Go to

`[your magento install dir]/skin/frontend/matt/tmd/css/styles.css`

First backup this file in a safe place before making any changes. After that open the file with a proper editor.

On line 632 you will find the following code:

```
.account-nav li {
    padding: 5px 0px;
}
```

Replace it with:

```
.account-nav li {
    padding: 0 8px;
}
```

Save the file, refresh cache and go to the frontend of your website to check the result.

> Please note that one of your `account-nav` links (the second) is empty. You should
>   check this too!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simple styling change. I would add some margin-left to the Checkout link to space it out from the Cart link.

This can be done in your styles file depending on your setup. You can find this in `skin/frontend/YOUR THEME/YOUR PACKAGE/css/styles.css`

Hope this helps,